# Unclear marking on a surface mount resistor

Tags: resistors, resistance, surface-mount

I have this resistor on a board.

Can someone can help me determine the value from the photo?

I did a ohms reading, and actually just around 22k Ohm. Which cannot be right. I asked about this in a previous post, but guess I needed a separate thread.

[image]

Comment: Why 22k cannot be right?

Comment: SMT resistors (at least the smaller packages) do not directly specify Ohms - there's not enough room. They use some specific code that (I believe) is unique to the vendor.

Comment: @td127 there's a canonical coding for SMD resistors. it's two digits of mantissa, and one for the exponent. The value is mantissa · 10^(exponent) Ω.

Comment: You didn't happen to measure the resistor *in* the circuit, did you, mnemonic?

Answer (score 1):

SMT resistors have gotten so small, they are often now coded with a scheme that does NOT show the actual resistance value.  (Not enough space to print the traditional code)

It's called the EIA-96 system.

https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/eia96-smd-resistors.php

Comment: I did not know this. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, I did not know this either (that the code was standardized).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't measure the value of a resistor with it in the circuit.  You must remove it from the board.
2. Surface mount resistors are usually marked with a 3 or 4 digit code.

For a 3 digit code, the two left digits are a number and the right most digit is the number of zeros to append to the value.  103 is the value 10 with three more zeroes appended - total value is 10000, or 10 kiloohms.

A four digit code has three value digits to the left and one digit for the number of zeroes. 1002 is 100 with 2 zeroes appended - that's 10000, or 10 kiloohms.

The code on your resistor is a little unclear.

It is a 3 digit code.  The left most digit is either 6 or 8. 624 would be 620 kiloohms, 824 would be 820 kiloohms.

You'll have to take it out and measure it if you can't get a better look at the left most digit.

Comment: @Passerby:  It's a surface mount part.  You can't practically disconnect one side.

Comment: although looking at those indents, an attempt was made

Comment: Hey guys. I am just replying to say I know exactly how the marking works on these resistors, and yes, I did measure in circuit as the rest reflected their markings correctly. I know a parallel combination of circuits can throw the expected value of, but as said I was wondering why the marking looks like that. I dont own a hot reflow system, so regular soldering and wick is what I use. Desoldering gun I have yes, with a silicone tube made on top of teflon piece to suck, but doesnt work all the time. I mean for instance a marking of 103 will mean 10K resistor. So I understand all this perfectly

Comment: And a 0 alone marking could mean a sensing resistor. So what is the first character in there, IN CASE, its a bad resistor when I managed to lift the one side from the board at least? Or will circuit analysis be my only way to get a estimate.

Comment: @mnemonic: [How to remove a resistor without breaking it.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-12removesmdpassive)

Comment: @JRE Thanks, just checked out that link. That is exactly how I did it over the past years, but as Kyle B for instance mentioned there exists a shorter naming scheme on these components which I have never seen for myself or heard of until now.

Comment: 820K resistor... 'Clever' me... thanks everyone

Comment: @JRE You were very right on the resistor. It was 820K indeed, on point. Guess I picked up on parallel circuits after all. Thanks. See you are from Deutschland. Grüsse aus Südafrika :)